# UI-updates with Background tasks on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a synchronisation process which sometimes (even rarely) takes 20 seconds. I used to call the selector in the background. There is a progress indicator which stops animating on a notification that the sync is finished, and with the code below it changes straight away:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateFunction) withObject:nil];
```

But in order to allow the progress to continue I decided to use the background task:

```
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object

    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid

        //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
    }];

    //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Perform your tasks that your application requires

        NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
        [self updateFunction];

        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
        NSLog(@"Finished in the background!");
    });
```

But now, when the task is finished the notifications is sent (and executed) but the cell in the table doesn't update until (sometimes) a significant amount of time. So it seems to me that the 'needs display' is not triggered when coming from a background task or so, and is only updated at a regular refresh interval or so.

Is there a way to have the table cell update using background tasks, or am I missing something?

Edit:
The notification listener is:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(refreshBttn)
                                             name:@"finishedUpdate"
                                           object:nil];
```

The code is:

```
- (void) refreshBttn {
    NSLog(@"Refresh Buttun action");
    iDomsAppDelegate *delegate = (iDomsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if([delegate updating]){
        [_updateBttn setHidden:TRUE];
        [_activityIndicator startAnimating];         
    } else {
        [_updateBttn setHidden:FALSE];
        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];        
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split up your logic between background and foreground threads. The notification you're sending should be sent from the main thread, so that your UI objects listening to it can update themselves safely. So, break up `updateFunction` into two pieces. Perhaps something like this:

```
NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
[self updateFunctionBackground];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // send your notification here instead of in updateFunction
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] post...];
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. In both occasions I can see the log entry I created when updating the cell, but no change in behaviour. (but having said that, it is better indeed, as now it is performed on the main thread)

Comment: @LuukD.Jansen Perhaps the problem is in your UI-updating code? What are you doing in there? Can you post the code for the receiver of that notification?

Comment: That doesn't seem the problem, as it works perfect in the first instance when I perform the update function just in the background. I will put the code, but it is fairly simple.

Comment: I changed my notification system so the notification is always posted on the main thread (and extra notification announcing the completion of the job and then a selector performed on the main thread to sent the notification). A few selectors, but this solved the problem. (I don't want to use block yet as I try to be 4.x compatible.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the UI to update you have to call the function on the main thread from your background thread like so:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateFunction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

If you need to pass any variables you can go ahead and add those in the `-withObject`

Comment: Actually, using [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateFunction) withObject:nil]; works. I will do a few tests to see if it performs it correctly int he background

Comment: I tested, when the application is closed it does not continue to run in the background. This only works with calling the update function directly (not in background on on main thread)

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that a notification is received from any queue you want with...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SomeNotification
                                                  object:sender
                                                   queue:operationQueue
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *){
    // Your notification will be processed in this block, and it will be
    // received on the notification queue you specify, regardless of what
    // thread the sender was running when the notification was posted.
}];
```

If you want to make sure it is received on the main thread, you can use

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
```

Comment: That is a good point. I'm still not used to these fancy iOS 5 APIs. :)

Comment: I am still trying to keep my code 4.x compatible, at least for another while as I do have quite a lot of 4.x users