# UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier running NSTimer but not updating UILabel - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nstimer, uibackgroundtask

In my app, I have `NSTimer` which updates UILabel every second. I've added `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` before `NSTimer` to let it run in background.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }];


timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:updateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

.
.
.

```
-(void)updateTime
{
    secondsLeft -= 1;
    //NSLog(@"Update time : %d ......",secondsLeft);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         _timeLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondsLeft];
    }); 
}
```

Problem is when we press home button app gets into background, timer is running but `uilabel` is not updating. E.g. Say, `_timeLbl` displaying '45'. Now if I press home button, app goes into background. After 10 sec. I click app icon to get app in foreground, and there I see '45' **for a while (fraction of second)** and then it display 35, instead of directly display 35. That means label is not getting updated with `NSTimer`. Is there any workaround to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: update text of your label in main queue

Comment: if you mean dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ......  }); .......tried this but no luck

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831412/ui-updates-with-background-tasks-on-ios)

Comment: @Nikhil I've checked that but didn't get all of it. Could you please provide solution as reference to this link and my question ?

Answer (score 1):

**App Delegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

}



- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

}];
 }
```

**YOUR CONTROLLER.M**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer1 {

int seconds = pauseTaskTime % 60;
int minutes = (pauseTaskTime - seconds) / 60;

lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d", minutes, seconds]
 }
```

**When you complete your code then follows these steps :**

```
1. Go to your project name.

2. Click Capabilities

3. On your Background Modes.
```

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)updateTime {
    secondsLeft -= 1;
    //NSLog(@"Update time : %d ......",secondsLeft);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        timeLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondsLeft];
    });
}
```

If you change it on main queue, it will get updated. I faced it long back and sorted in this way.

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261620/timer-that-updates-label-running-in-background

I am not able to see any linking between background task and update method in your code, so its not updating. 

You have 2 options:
1. Update your code to above one.
or
2. Use didEnterForeground method to update label again.

Comment: Thanks @Pushkraj, but I had visit this link before posting my question and did the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the label using a reference date instead of instance variable secondsLeft.

```
secondsLeft = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:referenceDate]
```

Comment: 1. I can't do this since its for objective test and retrieved secondsLeft from database. .......... 2. How this make a trick for the problem ?

Comment: Updating UI in background is not possible as far my knowledge goes, I would suggest you display a minor loader when app comes in foreground till the UI gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `-(void)updateTime` after setting the text in your label write `[_timeLbl layoutIfNeeded];`.

E.g:

```
-(void)updateTime
{
    secondsLeft -= 1;
    //NSLog(@"Update time : %d ......",secondsLeft);
    _timeLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondsLeft]; 
   [_timeLbl layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

layoutIfNeeded checks that the view is needed to be updated or not and updates if needed. I one word it refreshes the view.

Comment: ok then i have to check it out when i reach home, and will make you know if i got a solution

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine for me.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
    countDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeLeftSinceDate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:countDown forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: the question's code contains bgTask and that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
loop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:loop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CLLocation Manager's api for background timer update otherwise NSTimer allow 10 min execution in background .

try this  :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472381/3901620

and also add this in info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```